# C++ Boost Describe Recursive Struct iteration error

Tags: c++, struct, boost

I'm working on a code that recursively iterates through a struct using Boost library and puts bytes from a buffer into that struct.

```
template<typename Base, class Md = boost::describe::describe_members<Base, boost::describe::mod_any_access>>
    void Parser::copyBytesToStruct(Base& base){

        boost::mp11::mp_for_each<Md>([&](auto attr){
            this->copyBytesToStructInner(base.*attr.pointer);   
        });
    }

    template<typename Attr> 
    void Parser::copyBytesToStructInner(Attr& attr){

        //check if iterated type is struct, if it is then recursively call this function for it
        if(std::is_class<Attr>::value){
            this->copyBytesToStruct(attr);
        }
        else{
            int bytesToGet = sizeof(Attr);

            if (this->buffer->availableToCopy() < bytesToGet) {
                std::string typeName = boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<Attr>().pretty_name();
                std::cerr << "No more remaining data in buffer to read " + typeName;
                return;
            }

            int beginPtr = this->buffer->getBeginPtr();

            memcpy_s(this->buffer + beginPtr, this->buffer->availableToCopy(), &attr, bytesToGet);

            //if(!this->isBigEndian) __builtin_bswap(attr); todo: add some reverse logic here

            this->buffer->cutBytes(bytesToGet);
        }
    }
```

copyBytesToStruct will be initially called with a struct always.
Then I iterate through the members of the struct and inside of the inner template i check if that member is a struct, if it is i want to recursively iterate through that member also.

These are the structs I'm using and i described for boost:

```
namespace PE_STRUCTURE {

    struct DosHeader {

        WORD
            magic{}, //DOS .EXE header
            e_cblp{}, //Magic number
            e_cp{}, //Bytes on last page of file
            e_crlc{}, //Pages in file
            e_cparhdr{}, //Relocations
            e_minalloc{}, //Size of header in paragraphs
            e_maxalloc{}, //Minimum extra paragraphs needed
            e_ss{}, //Initial (relative) SS value
            e_sp{}, //Initial SP value
            e_csum{}, //Checksum
            e_ip{}, //Initial IP value
            e_cs{}, //Initial (relative) CS value 
            e_lfarlc{}, //File address of relocation table
            e_ovno{}, //Overlay number
            e_res[4]{}, //Reserved words
            e_oemid{}, //OEM identifier
            e_oeminfo{}, //OEM information 
            e_res2[10]{}; //Reserved words

        DWORD e_lfanew{}; //Address for NT Headers
    };

    BOOST_DESCRIBE_STRUCT(DosHeader, (), (magic, e_cblp, e_cp, e_crlc, e_cparhdr,
        e_minalloc, e_maxalloc, e_ss, e_sp, e_csum, e_ip, e_cs, e_lfarlc, e_ovno,
        e_res, e_oemid, e_oeminfo, e_res2, e_lfanew));

    //For PE32+ (64-bit) Executables
    struct ImageNtHeaders64 {

        DWORD signature{}; //almost always PE/0/0
        IMAGE_FILE_HEADER FileHeader{}; //Some information, has OptionalHeader size
        IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64 OptionalHeader{}; //Some important info
    };

    BOOST_DESCRIBE_STRUCT(ImageNtHeaders64, (), (signature, FileHeader, OptionalHeader));

    BOOST_DESCRIBE_STRUCT(IMAGE_FILE_HEADER, (), (Machine, NumberOfSections, TimeDateStamp,
        PointerToSymbolTable, NumberOfSymbols, SizeOfOptionalHeader, Characteristics));
        
    BOOST_DESCRIBE_STRUCT(IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32, (), (Magic, MajorLinkerVersion, MinorLinkerVersion,
        SizeOfCode, SizeOfInitializedData, SizeOfUninitializedData, AddressOfEntryPoint, BaseOfCode,
        BaseOfData, ImageBase, SectionAlignment, FileAlignment, MajorOperatingSystemVersion,
        MinorOperatingSystemVersion, Win32VersionValue, SizeOfImage, SizeOfHeaders, CheckSum,
        Subsystem, DllCharacteristics, SizeOfStackReserve, SizeOfStackCommit, SizeOfHeapReserve,
        SizeOfHeapCommit, LoaderFlags, NumberOfRvaAndSizes, DataDirectory));

    BOOST_DESCRIBE_STRUCT(IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64, (), (Magic, MajorLinkerVersion, MinorLinkerVersion,
        SizeOfCode, SizeOfInitializedData, SizeOfUninitializedData, AddressOfEntryPoint, BaseOfCode,
        ImageBase, SectionAlignment, FileAlignment, MajorOperatingSystemVersion,
        MinorOperatingSystemVersion, Win32VersionValue, SizeOfImage, SizeOfHeaders, CheckSum,
        Subsystem, DllCharacteristics, SizeOfStackReserve, SizeOfStackCommit, SizeOfHeapReserve,
        SizeOfHeapCommit, LoaderFlags, NumberOfRvaAndSizes, DataDirectory));

    BOOST_DESCRIBE_STRUCT(IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY, (), (VirtualAddress, Size))

    //For PE32 Executables
    struct ImageNtHeaders {

        DWORD signature{};
        IMAGE_FILE_HEADER FileHeader{};
        IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32 OptionalHeader{};
    };

    BOOST_DESCRIBE_STRUCT(ImageNtHeaders, (), (signature, FileHeader, OptionalHeader));
};
```

I'm getting errors like this when trying to build:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'PE_PARSER::Parser::copyBytesToStruct(short unsigned int&)'
   28 |             this->copyBytesToStruct(attr);

error: 'boost_public_member_descriptor_fn' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'PE_STRUCTURE::boost_public_member_descriptor_fn'?
   32 | template<class T> using _describe_public_members = decltype( boost_public_member_descriptor_fn( static_cast<T**>(0) ) );

error: no matching function for call to 'PE_PARSER::Parser::copyBytesToStruct(short unsigned int [4])'
   28 |             this->copyBytesToStruct(attr);

error: 'boost_public_member_descriptor_fn' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'PE_STRUCTURE::boost_public_member_descriptor_fn'?
   32 | template<class T> using _describe_public_members = decltype( boost_public_member_descriptor_fn( static_cast<T**>(0) ) );

error: no matching function for call to 'PE_PARSER::Parser::copyBytesToStruct(short unsigned int [10])'
   28 |             this->copyBytesToStruct(attr);

error: 'boost_public_member_descriptor_fn' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'PE_STRUCTURE::boost_public_member_descriptor_fn'?
   32 | template<class T> using _describe_public_members = decltype( boost_public_member_descriptor_fn( static_cast<T**>(0) ) );

error: no matching function for call to 'PE_PARSER::Parser::copyBytesToStruct(long unsigned int&)'
   28 |             this->copyBytesToStruct(attr);
      |             ^~~~

error: 'boost_public_member_descriptor_fn' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'PE_STRUCTURE::boost_public_member_descriptor_fn'?
   32 | template<class T> using _describe_public_members = decltype( boost_public_member_descriptor_fn( static_cast<T**>(0) ) );
```

It's almost like compiler is trying to call copyBytesToStruct with an integer, for which there is no BOOST_DESCRIBE_STRUCT - this template can be only used with structs.

I tried doing std::enable_if_t for both template functions, but the error remains the same:

```
template<typename Base, class Md = boost::describe::describe_members<Base, boost::describe::mod_any_access>>
std::enable_if_t<(std::is_class<Base>::value)> copyBytesToStruct(Base& base);
```

Any suggestions on what to do/what is going on here?

Minimal reproducible example:

StructureRepro.hpp:

```
#ifndef STRUCTURE_H
#define STRUCTURE_H

#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <winnt.h>

#include <boost/describe/class.hpp>

namespace PE_STRUCTURE {

    //For PE32+ (64-bit) Executables
    struct ImageNtHeaders64 {

        DWORD signature{}; //almost always PE/0/0
        IMAGE_FILE_HEADER FileHeader{}; //Some information, has OptionalHeader size
        IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64 OptionalHeader{}; //Some important info
    };

    BOOST_DESCRIBE_STRUCT(ImageNtHeaders64, (), (signature, FileHeader, OptionalHeader));

    BOOST_DESCRIBE_STRUCT(IMAGE_FILE_HEADER, (), (Machine, NumberOfSections, TimeDateStamp,
        PointerToSymbolTable, NumberOfSymbols, SizeOfOptionalHeader, Characteristics));

    BOOST_DESCRIBE_STRUCT(IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64, (), (Magic, MajorLinkerVersion, MinorLinkerVersion,
        SizeOfCode, SizeOfInitializedData, SizeOfUninitializedData, AddressOfEntryPoint, BaseOfCode,
        ImageBase, SectionAlignment, FileAlignment, MajorOperatingSystemVersion,
        MinorOperatingSystemVersion, Win32VersionValue, SizeOfImage, SizeOfHeaders, CheckSum,
        Subsystem, DllCharacteristics, SizeOfStackReserve, SizeOfStackCommit, SizeOfHeapReserve,
        SizeOfHeapCommit, LoaderFlags, NumberOfRvaAndSizes, DataDirectory));

    BOOST_DESCRIBE_STRUCT(IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY, (), (VirtualAddress, Size))
};

#endif
```

ParserRepro.cpp:

```
#include "StructureRepro.hpp"

#include <vector>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <type_traits>

#include <boost/mp11.hpp>
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
#include <boost/describe.hpp>

template<typename Attr> 
void copyBytesToStructInner(Attr& attr);

template<typename Base, class Md = boost::describe::describe_members<Base, boost::describe::mod_any_access>>
void copyBytesToStruct(Base& base){
    boost::mp11::mp_for_each<Md>([&](auto attr){
        copyBytesToStructInner(base.*attr.pointer);   
    });
}

template<typename Attr> 
void copyBytesToStructInner(Attr& attr){
    //check if iterated type is struct, if it is then recursively call this function for it
    if(std::is_class<Attr>::value){
        copyBytesToStruct(attr);
    }
}

void loadPEFileFromBinary() {
    PE_STRUCTURE::ImageNtHeaders64 st;
    copyBytesToStruct(st);
}
```

Comment: You might help readers by adding a complete example that can be easily copy-pasted to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Okey i will add necessary code, can i just link a github repo though? It would be easier, because all that has to be done is just a cmake command - dependencies are being downloaded via git submodules

Comment: @Michael21 What people really want to see is a [mre] contained in the question.

Comment: okey I will make it minimal

Answer (score 1):

### Out Of The Box

Note, according to my understanding, all WINAPI structures are C, so "POD" types (trivial and standard-layout). This means you can just memcpy the bytes...:

```
void loadPEFileFromBinary(std::vector<uint8_t> const& binary) {
    static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<PE_STRUCTURE::ImageNtHeaders64>);
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<PE_STRUCTURE::ImageNtHeaders64>);
    PE_STRUCTURE::ImageNtHeaders64 st;

    assert(
        binary.size() >= sizeof(PE_STRUCTURE::ImageNtHeaders64) &&
        "Binary size is less than the size of PE_STRUCTURE::ImageNtHeaders64, cannot copy bytes to struct");

    memcpy(&st, binary.data(), sizeof(st));
}
```

### Inside The Box

> It's almost like compiler is trying to call copyBytesToStruct with an integer, for which there is no BOOST_DESCRIBE_STRUCT - this template can be only used with structs.

That's exactly what your code does, indeed.

You can avoid it by making the condition constexpr:

```
if constexpr (std::is_class_v<Attr>) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " " << boost::typeindex::type_id<Attr>().pretty_name() << std::endl;
    copyBytesToStruct(attr);
} else {
    std::cout << "Handle manually " << boost::typeindex::type_id<Attr>().pretty_name() << std::endl;
}
```

Now, you also have to fix the const-ref qualifiers on the deduced types (or wrap them with `std::decay_t`.

This is my (non-windows) mockup. As a bonus I threw in handling of C-style arrays (as this is likely something you needed):

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1df3fffef29d8a64)**

```cpp
#include <boost/describe.hpp>
#include <boost/mp11.hpp>
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

namespace PE_STRUCTURE {
    using DWORD = uint32_t;
    struct IMAGE_FILE_HEADER {
        DWORD Machine, NumberOfSections, TimeDateStamp, PointerToSymbolTable, NumberOfSymbols,
            SizeOfOptionalHeader, Characteristics;
    };
    struct IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY {
        DWORD VirtualAddress, Size;
    };
    struct IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64 {
        DWORD Magic, MajorLinkerVersion, MinorLinkerVersion, SizeOfCode, SizeOfInitializedData,
            SizeOfUninitializedData, AddressOfEntryPoint, BaseOfCode, ImageBase, SectionAlignment,
            FileAlignment, MajorOperatingSystemVersion, MinorOperatingSystemVersion, Win32VersionValue,
            SizeOfImage, SizeOfHeaders, CheckSum, Subsystem, DllCharacteristics, SizeOfStackReserve,
            SizeOfStackCommit, SizeOfHeapReserve, SizeOfHeapCommit, LoaderFlags, NumberOfRvaAndSizes;
        IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY DataDirectory[16];
    };

    // For PE32+ (64-bit) Executables
    struct ImageNtHeaders64 {
        DWORD                   signature{};      // almost always PE/0/0
        IMAGE_FILE_HEADER       FileHeader{};     // Some information, has OptionalHeader size
        IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64 OptionalHeader{}; // Some important info
    };

    BOOST_DESCRIBE_STRUCT(ImageNtHeaders64, (), (signature, FileHeader, OptionalHeader));

    BOOST_DESCRIBE_STRUCT(IMAGE_FILE_HEADER, (),
                          (Machine, NumberOfSections, TimeDateStamp, PointerToSymbolTable, NumberOfSymbols,
                           SizeOfOptionalHeader, Characteristics));

    BOOST_DESCRIBE_STRUCT(IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64, (),
                          (Magic, MajorLinkerVersion, MinorLinkerVersion, SizeOfCode, SizeOfInitializedData,
                           SizeOfUninitializedData, AddressOfEntryPoint, BaseOfCode, ImageBase,
                           SectionAlignment, FileAlignment, MajorOperatingSystemVersion,
                           MinorOperatingSystemVersion, Win32VersionValue, SizeOfImage, SizeOfHeaders,
                           CheckSum, Subsystem, DllCharacteristics, SizeOfStackReserve, SizeOfStackCommit,
                           SizeOfHeapReserve, SizeOfHeapCommit, LoaderFlags, NumberOfRvaAndSizes,
                           DataDirectory));

    BOOST_DESCRIBE_STRUCT(IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY, (), (VirtualAddress, Size))
}; // namespace PE_STRUCTURE

template <typename Attr> void copyBytesToStructInner(Attr const& attr);
template <typename Element, size_t N> void copyBytesToStructInner(Element const (&arr)[N]);

template <typename Base, class Md = boost::describe::describe_members<Base, boost::describe::mod_any_access>>
void copyBytesToStruct(Base const& base) {
    boost::mp11::mp_for_each<Md>([&](auto attr) { copyBytesToStructInner(base.*attr.pointer); });
}

template <typename Element, size_t N> void copyBytesToStructInner(Element const (&arr)[N]) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " " << boost::typeindex::type_id<Element>().pretty_name() << std::endl;
    for (auto& el : arr) {
        copyBytesToStructInner(el);
    }
}

template <typename Attr> void copyBytesToStructInner(Attr const& attr) {
    // check if iterated type is struct, if it is then recursively call this function for it
    if constexpr (std::is_class_v<Attr>) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " " << boost::typeindex::type_id<Attr>().pretty_name() << std::endl;
        copyBytesToStruct(attr);
    } else {
        // std::cout << "Handle manually " << boost::typeindex::type_id<Attr>().pretty_name() << std::endl;
    }
}

void loadPEFileFromBinary() {
    PE_STRUCTURE::ImageNtHeaders64 st;
    copyBytesToStruct(st);
}

int main() {
    loadPEFileFromBinary();
}
```

Printing

```
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_FILE_HEADER] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_FILE_HEADER
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Element (&)[N]) [with Element = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY; long unsigned int N = 16] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
```

Or, with the "handle manually" line uncommented: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc83adeeb89044c8

```
Handle manually unsigned int
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_FILE_HEADER] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_FILE_HEADER
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Element (&)[N]) [with Element = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY; long unsigned int N = 16] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
void copyBytesToStructInner(const Attr&) [with Attr = PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY] PE_STRUCTURE::IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
Handle manually unsigned int
Handle manually unsigned int
```

Comment: Added a simplifying "Out of the box" answer section

Comment: yea i thought about memcpy, but the problem is that in every attribute of the struct i need to reverse the bytes, because of little endian format.

Comment: See Boost Endian conversions? https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/endian/doc/html/endian.html. But I agree, there can be some usage patterns where having generic/reusable machinery to do this can be worth the investment